# What happens to consciousness after death?

Tags: consciousness, life, death

Is it possible that our innate sense of self, our egocentric outlook on the world, could be wrong? After all, our brains are never REALLY connected; so we cannot know for sure that our consciousness is REALLY separated by anything else than space and time. What I mean is; Is it possible that there could be only a single universal consciousness of which we are all a part? Could this REALLY be how it is? Or are there any philosophical arguments against this view? I haven't been myself since I first had this thought and I'm dying for an answer. On the one hand it feels exhilarating, on the other hand it kinda kills one's self image. What do you people think?

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to examine the question one has posed.  Your question raises many others.  For example, what do these words mean to you: *connected, separated, possible, part, really, myself, self-image, consciousness?*

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. That there is "a single universal consciousness of which we are all a part" is a common thread in Buddhist and Hinduist traditions, see [Nondualism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondualism). In the West some philosophies can also be read in this way (neo-Platonism, [absolute idealism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_idealism)).  However, "what do you think" questions that invite personal opinions are off-topic on this SE.

Comment: What happens to a flame after it goes out?

Comment: I'm hoping you haven't died yet, and got your answer.

Comment: No one seems to have mentioned absolute monism, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advaita_Vedanta - this school holds that only Brahman is ultimately real, and all other beings are eminations or aspects of that transcendental identity. So you can follow the critiques of that, including the Buddhist one of anatta, the lack of any persistent self-essence, and sunyata, the dependence of things on causes and conditions. There is a widespread critique of absolute monism as a form of solipsism.

Answer (score 3):

## If it is true, so what? You cannot do anything with it anyway.

> Is it possible that our innate sense of self, our egocentric outlook on the world, could be wrong?

Yes, it could be. But at present, we have no indication that it is not right.

> After all, our brains are never REALLY connected;

I will assume you mean physically connected.

> so we cannot know for sure that our consciousness is REALLY separated by anything else than space and time.

This amounts to a an empty statement. You are saying: *our brains are separated by space and time* and then: *we do not know if our consciousness is connected by something other than space and time*. True and true but they do not lead us anywhere.

> What I mean is; Is it possible that there could be only a single universal consciousness of which we are all a part?

It is possible, yes, but we have no indication of this at the moment.

> Or are there any philosophical arguments against this view?

Well from a philosophical point of view it is — for instance — possible that nothing exists beyond [your brain in a vat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brain_in_a_vat) and everything that comes into it is just a simulation; that no physical reality exists and all you see and hear is just artificial stimuli. That is a possibility in just the same way as you proposal of connection/collective consciousness is.

But... so what?

You can also — possibly — fly by your own doing, by tapping into a hitherto unknown source of force that can propel you through the air and maybe even space. That is a possibility, [you cannot prove that it is not so](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evidence_of_absence).

But I do not foresee you in the near future climbing up on the nearest table and throwing yourself off of it in the hope that you will be able to tap into that unknown source of force before you land on the floor. Even if it **could** be true, you place no faith in it being so, now do you?

Hence, as long as you cannot point to anything that speaks for your proposition of a shared consciousness actually being true, it is a pointless exercise because for all practical intents and purposes it is not true.

> What happens to consciousness after death?

It — most likely — returns to the state it was in before birth. Where do you think your consciousness was before you were born?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't follow, if there is only a single universal consciousness of which we are all a part, that you are an eternal part, or even a part that persists for some limited time after death. The single universal consciousness could continue minus your consciousness which has been terminated by death.

The question whether when you are alive you are a part of a single universal consciousness is separate from the question whether when you are not alive you remain a part of that consciousness. The consciousness can plainly do without you, as it did before your consciousness began. Why not after your death as well ?

Comment: "... your consciousness which has been terminated by death". This is not provable. It's your *life* that is terminated by your death.

Comment: You have quoted out of context. I was talking about what could be the case. The point was that if his consciousness has been terminated by death then the single universal comsciousness could continue. It would simply be minus his existence. I was talking hypothetically. I would not be so crude as to make a blank, unargued claim that his or anyone else's consciousness will be terminated by death. My philosophical standards are higher than that. My own views about death and its aftermath make no appearance here.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those ideas that sticks to you when once you run into it. I can't shake it either. But for me, it evolved over time. It's easy to think dramatically about the consequences of a collective consciousness.

- Is hurting others is the same as hurting yourself
- When we die, do we merge with being itself and sense all life?

It's impossible to know. Any questions about the outcome of this way of thinking are purely speculative. Only a liar or a fool can answer your question confidently. That said, i have pondered this concept for a while and do have some interesting questions that might make you think.

You define the idea as a "single universal (un)consciousness" but i think that's wrong, you cannot attribute quantity (single) to consciousness. It is like the idea of time and space, it's just a thing that *is*, you cannot question it because you experience it. But the question might you might ask is why?

If you try to comprehend why you exist, why you able to think, why anything *"is"* rather than the more sensible default of *"isn't"*, you might feel the same sense of awe i do. It's a total mind fuck, the human mind is not capable of understanding such transcendent concepts.

It's impossible to fully understand the existence of consciousness. But in knowing that i cannot understand it i feel secure because in some ways **the things that we have no hope of understanding are the most true**. They lie outside the human ability to inevitably corrupt and re-purpose things we understand.

Ultimately my musings have lead me to the weird belief that consciousness is a universal and omnipresent force that is *focused* by locales of kinetic complexity at all scales. And by these rules we are the a greatly *focused* consciousness at our scale because of the unparalleled complexity of the brain. Also consider that this would mean

- A pebble rolling down a hill is aware to some degree
- Cities *think*
- Computers are already conscious (oops)
- Our encompassing universe is conscious and we are conscious of it while inhabiting it. Much like the cells of our bodies, and the particles of a cell and the atoms of the particle.

This is a more reasonable to me than the alternative idea of drawing a line in the sand saying "this object is not conscious, this simple organism might be, and i certainly am" does not make sense to me. There are no lines in the sand with anything natural, except for maybe a beach.

Comment: +1 Although I disagree that computers ever will be conscious. You might also look at near and shared death experiences.

Comment: I don't mean conscious as in 'behaves indistinguishable from humans'. I mean that it is experiencing the universe. Perhaps in a similar way to a single celled organism.

Comment: Or merely acts in a way that it appears to be experiencing the universe.  How would you tell the difference?

Comment: That's a good question. But it doesn't apply only to computers. It applies to everything that's not *you*. Is your friend conscious or is he/she just a soul-less zombie? Is that computer conscious or just acting like a human, who are generally believed to be conscious? The only thing you really know for sure is 'i think, therefore i am'.

Comment: I think that the way out of that is to realize that our consciousness is a simulation of what we think we are going to do. We estimate probabilities of future events and actions, and that includes our own actions. It was shown recently that brains constantly predict, and that this then matches the immediate future more closely or less. Consciousness is basically a prediction about what I'm going to be thinking and experiencing. In other words, we can simulate other minds because that increases survival, and as a side benefit, we get this self-simulation we call 'me'.

Answer (score 1):

If the following answers are strictly related only to one particular religion, you may ignore this.  If you can find anything sensible/true, you may search other websites and test them.

> Is it possible that our innate sense of self, our egocentric outlook
> on the world, could be wrong?

Of course. Scientific analysis is enough for **understanding** this. It can be **realized** only by self realization.  Actually all of us cannot maintain our ego throughout our life as it is now.  When people have certain experiences they may understand it.   You might have read about some people's anecdotes when they visited some places or when they met some great men.  Some of them have said that they felt like melting their ego when they visited such places or great persons.

> After all, our brains are never REALLY connected; so we cannot know
> for sure that our consciousness is REALLY separated by anything else
> than space and time.

Before asking about connections, you could ask this question to yourself:  "For the growth and development of brains do the things needed for it have any connection?"  If not possible, again my humble reply is about self realization.  Or you may google and find what great Non-dualists **who realized the truth** have said about it.

> What I mean is; Is it possible that there could be only a single
> universal consciousness of which we are all a part?

If I take your words **in literary sense** I would say that it is not possible because if you say so you mean you need to wait for something to happen/become.  Since you need not wait for a possibility, I am compelled to say so.  Also, since consciousness is eternal, unchanging, present at all times, immutable, undivided, and infinite we need not use the word--'parts'. You may verify this: [How is the "I" the universe?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/55193/how-is-the-i-the-universe/55201#55201) But if you consider only the essence of that question, again I say, "Of course"; but only up to a certain extent. This is because, if I said so it would be a denial of the words of great men who used the term 'non-dual' after realizing it.

> Could this REALLY be how it is?

Yes.

> Or are there any philosophical arguments against this view?

I don't know if there is.  If you wish to argue against this you may take your own idea as you mentioned about brains.  But when you realize yourself you realize that the creator and creation are one.  So you will 'get' the proof from within you.

See:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitanya_(consciousness)

> I haven't been myself since I first had this thought and I'm dying for
> an answer. On the one hand it feels exhilarating, on the other hand it
> kinda kills one's self image. What do you people think?

You are right. It will kill the self image that you misunderstood that it is strictly related to your body as in a delusion. But you need not fear of some great loss.  Please listen to [Sri Ramana Maharshi's parable of salt doll.](http://www.wisdompills.com/2015/11/08/the-salt-doll/)

> What happens to consciousness after death?

When you realize yourself you will understand that there is no birth and death to the self. Please read the first link about consciousness and then read [the Bhagavad Gita 2.20.](https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2/verse/20)

Answer (score 1):

I see a mayor problem with your question(s). It appears that you do not realize that there are at least two types/levels of "consciousness" (three if you believe in a "supreme" being). They are:

1 - Individual
2 - Group
3 - Transcendent/universal

So, obviously, there are three answers to your main question.

1 - The individual's consciousness ceases to exist, when the individual dies.
2 - The group's consciousness ceases to exist, when all the group's members die (or are no longer a group).
3 - The transcendent consciousness **never ceases to exist**, as it does not depend on any individual or group.

This makes it clear that for an individual's consciousness to continue to exist, after death, is to somehow **become part** of the transcendent (supreme being's)  consciousness!